# How to change some part of text in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set with million rows. And I have a huge list of keywords :

```
AS     Alan Sir
BFD    Baba Farda Dobare
```

And so on. I want each row if it has `AS`, change it to `Alan Sir`, if it has `BFD`, change it to `Baba Farda Dobare`.

How I can do that in PySpark?

Comment: Is your list of keywords also a Spark dataframe?

Comment: No. It is not that much big

Comment: So it's a Python list? Or dict?

Comment: it is a txt file with 200 rows. I can make it list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the txt file into a dictionary, and use `df.replace` to replace the values according to the dictionary mapping. You can also specify which column to replace using the `subset` parameter:

```
df2 = df.replace({'AS': 'Alan Sir', 'BFD': 'Baba Farda Dobare'}, subset = ['column1'])
```

However this only works for exact matches. For non-exact matches, you can use the other `replace` function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce
df2 = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x.withColumn(
        'column1', F.expr(f"replace(column1, '{y[0]}', '{y[1]}')")
    ),
    my_dict.items(),
    df
)
```

Comment: it doen 't change anything

Comment: sample data? @Nagh

Comment: sure, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227152/discussion-between-mck-and-nagh